# question about the deﬁnition of the deﬁnite integral

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Assume f and g are functions that are both integrable on the closed interval [a, b]. Prove that if f(x) ≤ g(x) for all x then
integral of f(x) from a to b is ≤the integral of g(x) from a to b.(using just the deﬁnition of the deﬁnite integral.)

I tried to prove it by contradiction and let epsilon=1/2(integral of f(x) from a to b-integral of g(x) from a to b) while I can not succeed to get the answer.

Could someone help me to finish it?I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $L(f, P)$ and $U(f, P)$ are the lower and upper Riemann sums for $f$ on partition $P$, and similarly for $L(g, P)$ and $U(g, P)$, show that
$$
L(f, P)\leq L(g, P)\qquad\text{and}\qquad U(f, P)\leq U(g, P)
$$
for every partition $P$ of $[a,b]$.

Comment: sorry, I also can't finish it with your hint.Can you show me some processes?

Comment: Were you able to show that $U(f, P)\leq U(g, P)$ for all $P$?  Because then you're basically done -- if the integrals exist, then $U(f,P)\to\int_a^b f\,dx$ and $U(g,P)\to\int_a^b g\,dx$ as the width of the largest part of $P$ tends to $0$.  So, you can find a sequence $P_n$ of partitions which make the upper sums tend to the integrals.  But limits respect inequalities.